# write.xlsx function gives error when defining path with the file name but read.xlsx is fine

Tags: r, rjava, r-xlsx

I have a problem with the `write.xlsx2` function of `xlsx` R package. For instance, see the code below.

```
main_path<-"~/mydir/"
read.xlsx2(paste0(main_path,"my_input_excel.xlsx"), sheetIndex=1)
a<-1
write.xlsx2(a, paste0(main_path,"my_output_excel.xlsx"), sheetName="Sheet1", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE)
```

While `read.xlsx2` function works fine, `write.xlsx2` function gives the error

> Error in `.jnew("java/io/FileOutputStream", jFile)` :
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mydir/my_output_excel.xlsx (No such
>   file or directory)

When I remove the `paste0` part and write only the file name everything is fine again. So the problem is to define path.

p.s I am wondering, perhaps the `write.xlsx` ignores the tilde `~` so path definition becomes garbage.

Comment: Try replacing main_path with `path.expand("~/mydir/")`

Comment: Very valuable hint @James, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replacing "~/" with "Users//" works for Mac (probably for Linux as well). Though, it still eludes me how `read.xlsx` and `write.xlsx` could differ in such a fundamental way.